# How did Brian Cruikshank know that Hamilton Bartholomew was really Carson Dyle?

Tags: plot-explanation, charade

In the thrilling finale of *Charade* (1963), when Brian Cruikshank (Cary Grant) sees Hamilton Bartholomew (Walter Matthau) and yells for Regina "Reggie" Lampert (Audrey Hepburn) to stop running, Cruikshank recognizes Bartholomew as Carson Dyle.

How did he know that was Carson Dyle? I don't recall any plot point that serves this recognition on Cruikshank's part.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a definitive answer, but note that Cruikshank had researched the case enough to hook up with Scobie, Panthollow, and Gideon.  Perhaps he had scene photos of them with Carson Dyle.